Removing an array object from main Object
I am trying to remove an array object based on value of array object property by using JSONATA transform function but the array object is not getting removed. If pmtDtls.lnAprvlStatus ='D', the object in the pmtDtls should be removed.
Input data is
{
    "compCode": "0002",
    "pmtDtls": [
        {
         "partnerType": "V",
        "partnerId": "0001",
        "partnerName": "Partner 1",
        "payAmt": 1000,
        "lnAprvlStatus": "A",
        "payDesc": "nkjfkjfk nknfknk jkjkj"
    },
    {
        "partnerType": "V",
        "partnerId": "0005",
        "partnerName": "Partner 2",
        "payAmt": 2000,
        "lnAprvlStatus": "D",
        "payDesc": "fkjfk jfkfjkf jfkfjf"
    }
]

}
JSONATA expression being used is
$ ~> |{}| {}, pmtDtls[lnAprvlStatus='D'] |
I am expecting an output after removal of pmtDtls.lnAprvlStatus = 'D' as
{
  "compCode": "0002",
  "pmtDtls": [
    {
      "partnerType": "V",
      "partnerId": "0001",
      "partnerName": "Partner 1",
      "payAmt": 1000,
      "lnAprvlStatus": "A",
      "payDesc": "nkjfkjfk nknfknk jkjkj"
    }
  ]
}

but the same object as input is being returned

$merge([$, { "pmtDtls": $.pmtDtls[lnAprvlStatus != "D"] }])
or
$ ~> | pmtDtls | {}, lnAprvlStatus = "D" ? $keys() |
should help you get the result you need.
Update 8 Aug 2024
As suggested by Andreas below, there is a cleaner solution:
$ ~> |$|{ "pmtDtls": $.pmtDtls[lnAprvlStatus != "D"] }|
Link to JSONata playground: https://jsonatastudio.com/playground/51e20591

Thanks for the help. Both the options gives correct result. However second option creates a blank object also in the result, which may be due to filtered sub Object not being part of the result. Thanks again

No problem. Yes, the second expression does leave blank objects which need filtering out with another expression.

Here's how you can modify your expression to achieve this:
{
  "compCode": compCode,
  "pmtDtls": pmtDtls[lnAprvlStatus != "D"]
}

This expression will transform the input data by removing the pmtDtls object where lnAprvlStatus is "D", resulting in the expected output.

compCode retains the compCode property from the input.
pmtDtls[lnAprvlStatus != "D"] filters the pmtDtls array to
exclude objects where lnAprvlStatus equals "D".


Thanks for your answer. It works !!! However my problem is - there are many more properties in the real object at the root level, which I removed in the question for easy understanding. To make it work as suggested by you, I need to write down all such properties in the jsonata expression. Is there any other way which can do it more efficiently?

{
"compCode": compCode,
"pmtDtls": pmtDtls[lnAprvlStatus != "D"],
**@$**
}
**@$** is a wildcard that includes all other properties from the original object without explicitly specifying them.

This did not produce the result. I tried various other combinations of this path traversal without any success.

Just had something similar. In my opinion this is the most intuitive solution:
$ ~> | $ | {
    "pmtDtls": $.pmtDtls[lnAprvlStatus != "D"]
} |

This will not return empty objects and will only removearray members from pmtDtls - all other keys that may exist won't be removed.
